# Sql server 2008:Permission to access database properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

What is the minimum permission(server roles and user mapping) by which properties of database can be viewed in sql server 2008?
Now i hav given only public and datareader in user mappings and public in server role.When i right click on database and click on properties i am getting error like "User '' does not have permission to run DBCC showfilestats for database '"

Comment: I Googled the error message (hint...) and discovered that this is a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980037) but apparently it was fixed in [SP1 CU7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979065). Have you installed the latest servicepack (SP3)?

Comment: I have gone through that article before only.I have installed latest service pack and again i am getting same error.

Comment: It's not a problem with Sql server service pack.The problem is with SSMS. I have installed SSMS 2008 R2 service pack 2 and problem is solved now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have access to db_owner fixed database role or Sysadmin fixed server role.